# Swift: Disable touches on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a UITableView on top of a MKMapView. I want to have similar functionality to how Apple's Maps app works. Where you can move a table up and down but still be able to move the map that is behind it. Right now I have a blank cell at index 0 that is clear and I want to be able to disable all touches that that cell receives and allows the map behind it to move, but when the cell in index 1 is touched that cell can scroll up and the rest of the table is now on top of the map.

If there is a better way to solve this problem I am up to try your solution!

Comment: you can disable touch on cell from interfaces builder where you will find property for tableview called Selection and set it with "No Selection" value.

Comment: @Hosny That only makes the cell not selectable, but will still allow the non selectable cell to move the table the cell is in. I need the cell and the table to not move on touch movements but allow the map behind both the cell and the table to move.

Answer (score 3):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt
 indexPath: IndexPath){

    //UITableViewCell *cell = something

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
         cell.selectionStyle = .none
         cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }


 }
```

What this code does is it makes sure that the cell is not highlighted when the user taps it. And then the second line in the `if` is to make sure that `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not called which will be the case if the line is left out, and even though selectionStyle is none!

Comment: So that stops the interaction on the cell, but the touch does not pass through the cell to the map. The touch still interacts with the table the cell is in.

Comment: @Averex So I am kind of curious, because if you put the table view above the map, and have the first cell is not responding to the user's touch, how should it impact the MapView? And as I look at Apple Maps, the first row (index 0) is also pulling up the table,  but not moving the map at all. So I am not sure what do you mean by "touch does not pass through the cell to the map" because as far as I know, if there is any element on top of the map, and you touch it, the map does not respond to the touch.

Comment: To answer your first question, I want the blank cell to be a buffer so the cell at index 1 can start near the bottom of the screen. I don't want the user to use the blank cell to move the table i just want it as a buffer for index 1 cell and then any touches to the blank cell will never be acting on the table but override the table to allow the map behind it to be used.

Is there any other way to make the buffer without a blank cell?

Comment: @Averex I am not sure if that is possible, however I am confident that you could do some really hacky way of putting it all together like that but not sure if it would be recommended. I would say if you don't want to hinder with the map, maybe try using better constraints to place the table in the way you want it to be!